# Nginx redirect - what am I doing wrong?

Tags: nginx, redirect

The original url is https://www.mywebsite.com/women/shoes_1-+-1~2.html
The redirected url should be https://www.mywebsite.com/women/shoes.html

```
rewrite ^/women/shoes_1-+-1~2\.html /women/shoes.html permanent;
```

I am sure the answer is simple but I don`t see it!

---

Thank you for your help.
The problem was that I did not put "\" before the "-" and "+". 
The final version that I used is:

```
rewrite ^/women/shoes_1\-\+\-1~2\.html /women/shoes.html permanent;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would do it like this:

```
location ~ ^/women/shoes_1\-\+1~2\.html$ {
    rewrite ^(.*)$ /women/shoes.html permanent;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

For the best performance, I would try:

```
location = /women/shoes_1-+-1~2.html {
    return 301 https://www.mywebsite.com/women/shoes.html;
}
```

Note that rewrite directives and regex locations are dependent on their position in your config. By avoiding them, your config will scale more smoothly.